# Service Fabric load balance timeout

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have two .net core webapi apps (appA and appB), dockerized, running in three service fabric nodes (node1, node2 and node3). The service fabric is running in the Azure with a load balancer.

When I have a request from outside works well.

When I have a internal request from appA to appB, across node1 to node2, works well too.

But seems when the load balancer decides to route a request from appA to appB in the same node, I got a timeout. For example:

A request from outside to appA inside node1, so appA asks the load balancer to access appB. Load balancer routes the request to node1 (same origin node). Then I got timeout.

The "problematic" flow:

Request from **web** -> **load balancer** -> **node1** -> **appA** (at this point, the app will need info from the olther service) -> **load balancer** (and here seems I got the timeout) -> **node1** -> **appB**.

Does someone face the same problem, or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Azure LoadBalancer, as the name suggest, split the incoming load between the nodes(VM) behind it, in your case, you have 3 nodes(VM) behind a load balancer and each connection to a load balancer will be forwarded to one node(VM).

The simplest way to solve this problem is make a request via the Service Fabric Reverse Proxy, when enabled, a reverse proxy will be available on all nodes, so every request coming through the LB will find a RP(Reverse Proxy) in the node. The reverse proxy will handle the work to find the container in your cluster, does not matter if they are on same node or another.

In the end, the external client will make a request to something like:

```
http://{sf-cluster-fqdn}:19081/DockerSFAppName/ContainerName/<any-path-inside-your-container>
```

Please take a look in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#special-handling-for-services-running-in-containers)

If you don't want to provide the ApplicationName and Container name to reach your container your have the following options:

- Use another reverse proxy engine, like suggested the @4c74356b41 and manually configure it to forward to your containers or translate it to a reverse proxy call inside the cluster. My recommendation would be [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/servicefabric/)
- Build your own ReverseProxy, with the rules you need to forward the request
- Deploy one instance of each container to every node, not ideal but an option

Comment: Yeap, I'll try to use some other reverse proxy, because, following the azure service fabric docs, the "native" reverse proxy works with windows only, and my cluster is linux based.

Comment: In this case you should try Traefik or Nginx

Comment: I used that https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric-reverse-proxy/blob/master/deploy/Linux_Reverse_Proxy.md

Answer (score 0):

this is a known limitation, node cant talk to itself using the load balancer. only real work around is to use some proxy like nginx to handle that. so your traffic will go like this:

```
appA - nginx - load balancer - appb
```

Alternatively you can use application gateway (a PaaS offering)

Comment: I have a linux cluster, running my .net core apps in docker linux. could I have nginx like a reverse proxy or something like that? how would it work?